# Setting working directory

Tags: r

I try to set the working directory to a specific sub-folder x1 which is in folder y. R gives me this output:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/Statistics/Assignments/Assignment 4")
```

so i know that the working directory has been set to Assignment 4.

However, when I run the command `getwd()`, the result shows that the working directory is "Assignment 5".

```
getwd()
[1] "/Users/anirudhmaru/Desktop/Statistics/Assignments/Assignment 5"
```

Tried this multiple times but no success. Please help.

Comment: Maybe try `setwd("/Users/anirudhmaru/Desktop/Statistics/Assignments/Assignment 4")`?

Comment: I would suggest removing spaces when naming your directories. You can use "_" instead... :)

Answer (score 1):

In the window down next to the right corner, next to the console, search the `File` tab and then your directory there, then click on `More` -> `Set as working directory`

Tip: avoid spaces on my working directories, for instance, use: `Ass‌​ignment4` instead of `Ass‌​ignment 4`.